# Como usar moment.js com data vindo de um input date?

Tags: angular, momentjs

Tenho a seguinte form:

```
<form name="formConsultaPeriodo">
    Data Inicial
    <input class="form-control dataIni" type="date" name="dataIni" ng-model="consulta.dataInicial" required />
    Data Final
    <input class="form-control dataFim" type="date" name="dataFim" ng-model="consulta.dataFinal" required />
    <a class="btn btn-success" ng-disabled="formConsultaPeriodo.$invalid" ng-click="consultaPeriodo(consulta)">Consultar</a>
</form>
```

Meu controller:

```
$scope.consultaPeriodo = function(consulta){
    var dataInicial = consulta.dataInicial;
    var dataFinal = consulta.dataFinal;
    console.log("dataInicial "+dataInicial+" dataFinal "+dataFinal);

}
```

Não quero que saia nesse formato

> dataInicial Thu Jan 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0200 (-02) dataFinal Fri Jan 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0200 (-02)

Quero saber como formatar as data digitadas nos campos e usando o moment.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não sei se entendi sua pergunta, mas supondo que seu input retornou algo como (**2018-04-03T03:00:00.000Z**)

```
const consulta.dataInicial = "2018-04-03T03:00:00.000Z";
```

você pode usar o **Momen**t da seguinte forma:

```
moment(consulta.dataInicial).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
// 2018-04-03 00:00:00
```

**ou**

```
moment(consulta.dataInicial).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss');
// 03-04-2018 00:00:00
```

**ou**

```
moment(consulta.dataInicial).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
// 03/04/2018
```

> Existe várias formas, depende da forma que deseja salvar.

Comment: Então eu teria que pegar a variável com a data e colocar ela dentro de moment? Dessa forma? moment("dataInicial").format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');

Comment: Isso mesmo, valeu Glauber